# How to find out time.Sleep() in the execution path?

Tags: go

Trying to find out time.Sleep() call in the execution path.

To simplify the problem, consider the code below.

```golang
func BenchmarkSleep(b *testing.B) {
    for i:=0; i < b.N; i++ {
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 10)
    }
}
```

I tried to profile (cpu, block, mutex) the code and expected to see the `time.Sleep` samples in the profile.

What should I do.

Comment: time.Sleep is in line 3 of your code. Grepping works well for this kind of task. But maybe I do not understand what your actual problem is. Maybe your simplified problem is too much simplified?

Comment: What I mean is if the time.Sleep is not so apparently like the code above, and it's hard to find it out by code review. How can I find it by using profiling tool (pprof) or something else.

Comment: What IDE are you using? In GoLand I would open the project, find (or add) a call to `time.Sleep()` right-click and select "Find Usages".

Comment: It's not likely to turn up much in a profiler because it consumes practically no resources, that's the point of `Sleep`; it yields the CPU for the given amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you  tried:

`go test -trace trace.out`

followed by:

`go tool trace trace.out`

... to view it in a browser?

You can then generate a pprof-like profile from the trace:

`go tool trace -pprof=TYPE trace.out > TYPE.pprof`

Supported profile types are:

- net: network blocking profile
- sync: synchronization blocking profile
- syscall: syscall blocking profile
- sched: scheduler latency profile

And view that too:

`go tool pprof TYPE.pprof`

More generally...

The trace package: https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/trace/

Can be used with the trace tool: https://golang.org/cmd/trace/

To get diagnostics and visualise the profiling data: https://golang.org/doc/diagnostics.html